# biblatex citation problem "Citation x on page y undefined on input line z"

Tags: sublimetext3, pdflatex, biblatex

Im having the "Citation x on page y undefined on input line z" problem but everyone online just keeps saying:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jc8b.png

Please explain in detail what this actually means and how to solve this issue.

I aim initialising biblatex in sublime and adding the bib resource with full file paths.
**However** the file paths have a space in them and I have yet to find out how to deal with this in sublime.

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/DrSalty//Google Drive//PhD/Reports/library.bib}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/DrSalty//Google Drive//PhD/Reports/ManualRefs.bib}


\begin{document}
\title{x}
\author{y}
\date{Day Month Year}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}
Blah \cite{Todo2019}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here someone have had a similar problem / question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578406 :: apparently you may check your biber version, according to the comments at the referenced answer

Answer (score 1):

So I shouldn't actually have to even care about the compiling order as it IS automatic. I wish people would stop saying this as a response to the "Citation x on page y undefined on input line z" issue.

The real solution was that sublime cant deal with spaces in file paths automatically and neither can bibtex/biblatex (as I expected), but the '//' method I'm used to using for dealing with this in the cmd for things like python doesn't work.
***Instead** for some god awful reason!* it supports LEGACY DOS PATHS!?

The link to the solution and explanation of this god awful thing:
https://www.edwinwenink.xyz/posts/32-bibtex_dynamic_path_w_spaces/